# How to load a js source in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, spring

I am trying to load an js script source in a html page that is in a Spring MVC server.

**Folder in Spring MVC**

> The html page is located here: **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/mapa.html**
>
> The js is located in a view subfolder:
>   **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/js/infobox.js**

This is my html page  **mapa.html**

> ```
>     <!DOCTYPE html>
>     <html>
>       <head>
>        <style>
>       #map_canvas {
>         width: 500px;
>         height: 400px;
>       }
>     </style>
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
>     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
>     <!-- Caixa de informação -->
>     <script src="js/infobox.js"></script>
>     <!-- Agrupamento dos marcadores -->
>     <script src="js/markerclusterer.js"></script>
>     </head>
>    <body>
>    //code...
>    </body>
>    </html>   `
> ```

I am trying to load the infobox.js in the mapa.html using but it is not loading.
is this source route correct??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your relative path is good, but you probably have a missing configuration in Spring MVC that will help serve static resources efficiently. In your case, spring mvc configuration should hold something like

```
<resources mapping="/js/**" location="/WEB-INF/views/js/" />
```

better approach is to have a resources folder in the root of your webapp, and an entry like this in your spring mvc config

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

and place all of your static resources inside the resources subfolders and access them via

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/..."></script>
```

similiarly for css

Comment: Any idea about add this `<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />`  using some `@Bean` method? I am using `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in a Spring Application.

Comment: ok, so you're using spring-boot, as far as I know, resources should be one od the default locations already mapped. Easy to test at least, just move your /js folder to /resources folder available at webaapp root, and try accessing by /resources/js.. from the page. Should work

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<script src="./view/js/infobox.js"></script>
```

and

```
 <script src="./view/js/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```